# Copy, rename and validate success of multiple files and paths in excel

Tags: excel, vba, validation, copy, rename

[Solution Template SetUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlgwL.jpg)

Been scratching around for the last 5 days here and across the net to find something that works for multiple files. Many a late night/early hours of the morning unsuccessfully piecing together/coding to get a result.  Thanks in advance.

The following code is from get-digital-help.com/copyrename-a-file-excel-vba written by Oscar
It works for 1 file, Ive got 8,000 files to do across a deep folder structure so but I'd really like each row to look at a source path, source file name, destination path and destination file:

For each row:

- Column A list the source path
- Column B lists the source file name
- Column C lists to destination path
- Column D lists the new file name

Column E writes "Success" or "Fail" validation.

- if file name already exists in destination, then "Fail"
- If source file doesn't exist, then "Fail"

Nice to have/completely optional!!! :)

1. Check if source file column A&B exists, = True or False in column F. Where True, then proceed with copy and rename.
2. If destination file already exist, the fail and column F = duplicate
3. Leave first row to put in column header names.

`Sub CopyRenameFile()

'Dimension variables and declare data types
Dim src As String, dst As String, fl As String
Dim rfl As String

'Save source directory specified in cell A2 to variable src
src = Range("A2")

'Save destination directory specified in cell C2 to variable dst
dst = Range("C2")

'Save file name specified in cell B2 to variable fl
fl = Range("B2")

'Save new file name specified in cell D2 to variable rfl
rfl = Range("D2")

'Enable error handling
On Error Resume Next

'Copy file based on variables src and fl to destination folder based on variable dst and name file based on value in rfl
FileCopy src & "\" & fl, dst & "\" & rfl

'Check if an error has occurred
If Err.Number <> 0 Then

'Show error using message box
    MsgBox "Copy error: " & src & "\" & rfl
End If

'Disable error handling
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub`

Comment: You can use `Dir(fullPathHere)` to check if a file exists or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Files Using a File List

- This solution consists of three procedures. You run only the first: `copyRenameFile`. The other two, `getOffsetColumn` and `writeOffsetRange` are being called by the first, when necessary.
- It is best tested with a new workbook. Insert a module and copy the code into it. Now open your original workbook and copy certain values to e.g. `Sheet1` of the new workbook. Since the code is written for `Thisworkbook` (the workbook containing this code), the original workbook will be safe (will not be written to).
- First adjust the values in the constants sections (titled `Worksheet` and `Other`). Then test the empty worksheet. Then test with one folder in column `A` then with more and slowly continue testing with other columns. Possible errors should be suppressed and their messages (descriptions) should appear in `VBE`'s `Immediate` window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).
- As a byproduct of this investigation, I've also added the `createFolders` function to create folders in one case when `MkDir` 'cannot', and two procedures to test it.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyRenameFile()

    ' Initialize error handling.
    Const ProcName As String = "copyRenameFile"
    On Error GoTo clearError ' Turn on error trapping.
    
    ' Worksheet
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"        ' Worksheet Name
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2               ' First Row Number
    Const LastRowCol As Variant = "A"        ' Last Row Column Index
    Dim srcCols As Variant                   ' Source Columns Array
    srcCols = VBA.Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
    Dim tgtCols As Variant                   ' Target Columns Array
    tgtCols = VBA.Array("E", "F")
    
    ' Other
    Dim filMsg() As Variant                  ' File Messages
    filMsg = VBA.Array("Fail", "Success")
    Dim folMsg() As Variant                  ' Folder Messages
    folMsg = VBA.Array(False, True, "Duplicate")
    Dim PathDelimiter As String
    PathDelimiter = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' 'Thisworkbook' is the workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Define Last Row Column Range ('rng').
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, LastRowCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If LastRow < FirstRow Then
        GoTo FirstRowBelowLastRow
    End If
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, LastRowCol), _
                       ws.Cells(LastRow, LastRowCol))
     
    ' Write Source Column Ranges to Source Jagged Array ('Source').
    Dim ubcS As Long
    ubcS = UBound(srcCols)
    Dim Source As Variant
    ReDim Source(0 To ubcS)
    Dim Data As Variant
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 0 To ubcS
        getOffsetColumn Data, srcCols(j), rng
        Source(j) = Data
    Next j
    
    ' Define Target Jagged Array ('Target').
    Dim ubcT As Long
    ubcT = UBound(tgtCols)
    Dim ubs As Long
    ubs = UBound(Source(0))
    Dim Target As Variant
    ReDim Target(0 To ubcT)
    ReDim Data(1 To ubs, 1 To 1)
    For j = 0 To ubcT
        Target(j) = Data
    Next j
    
    ' Declare additional variables for the For Next loop.
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Copied As Long
    Dim srcPath As String
    Dim tgtPath As String
    
    ' Loop through rows of arrays of Source Jagged Array, check folders,
    ' check files and finally copy if condition is met. At the same time
    ' write results to arrays of Target Jagged Array.
    ' The condition to copy is met when source file exists,
    ' and target file does not.
    
    For i = 1 To ubs
        
        ' Folders
        srcPath = Source(0)(i, 1)
        If Dir(srcPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            ' Source Folder and Source File do not exist.
            Target(0)(i, 1) = filMsg(0)
            Target(1)(i, 1) = folMsg(0)
            GoTo NextRow
        End If
        ' Source Folder exists.
        tgtPath = Source(1)(i, 1)
        If Dir(tgtPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            ' Target Folder and Target File do not exist.
            Target(0)(i, 1) = filMsg(0)
            Target(1)(i, 1) = folMsg(0)
            GoTo NextRow
        End If
        ' Source Folder and Target Folder exist.
        
        ' Files
        srcPath = srcPath & PathDelimiter & Source(2)(i, 1)
        If Dir(srcPath) = "" Then
            ' Source File does not exist.
            Target(0)(i, 1) = filMsg(0)
            Target(1)(i, 1) = folMsg(0)
            GoTo NextRow
        End If
        ' Source File exists.
        tgtPath = tgtPath & PathDelimiter & Source(3)(i, 1)
        If Dir(tgtPath) <> "" Then
            ' Target File exists.
            Target(0)(i, 1) = filMsg(0)
            Target(1)(i, 1) = folMsg(2)
            GoTo NextRow
        End If
        ' Source File exists and Target File does not.
        Target(0)(i, 1) = filMsg(1)
        Target(1)(i, 1) = folMsg(1)
        
        ' Copy
        FileCopy srcPath, tgtPath
        ' Count files copied.
        Copied = Copied + 1
         
NextRow:
    Next i
    
    ' Write values (results) from arrays of Target Jagged Array
    ' to Target Columns.
    For j = 0 To ubcT
        writeOffsetRange Target(j), tgtCols(j), rng
    Next j

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Copied " & Copied & " files.", vbInformation, "Success"

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

FirstRowBelowLastRow:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': First row below last row."
    GoTo ProcExit

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error trapping.
    GoTo ProcExit
    
End Sub

Sub getOffsetColumn(ByRef Data As Variant, _
                    OffsetColumnIndex As Variant, _
                    ColumnRange As Range)
    
    ' Initialize error handling.
    Const ProcName As String = "getOffsetColumn"
    On Error GoTo clearError ' Turn on error trapping.
    
    Data = Empty
    If ColumnRange Is Nothing Then
        GoTo NoRange
    End If
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ColumnRange.Worksheet
    
    If ColumnRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        Data = ColumnRange.Offset(, ws.Columns(OffsetColumnIndex).Column _
                                  - ColumnRange.Column) _
                          .Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        Data(1, 1) = ColumnRange.Offset(, ws.Columns(OffsetColumnIndex) _
                                            .Column _
                                        - ColumnRange.Column) _
                                .Value
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

NoRange:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': No Range."
    GoTo ProcExit

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error trapping.
    GoTo ProcExit

End Sub

Sub writeOffsetRange(Data As Variant, _
                     OffsetColumnIndex As Variant, _
                     ColumnRange As Range)
    
    ' Initialize error handling.
    Const ProcName As String = "writeOffsetColumn"
    On Error GoTo clearError ' Turn on error trapping.
    
    If ColumnRange Is Nothing Then
        GoTo NoRange
    End If
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ColumnRange.Worksheet
    
    ColumnRange.Offset(, ws.Columns(OffsetColumnIndex).Column _
                       - ColumnRange.Column).Value = Data

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

NoRange:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': No Range."
    GoTo ProcExit

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error trapping.
    GoTo ProcExit

End Sub
```

**The Byproduct**

```
' e.g. "C:\Test" is an existing folder, "C:\Test\Test1" is not.
' When you want to create the folder "C:\Test\Test1\Test2", 'MkDir' will return
' "Run-time error '76': Path Not found", because "C:\Test\Test1" does not exist.
' The 'createFolders' function remedies this by creating as many folders
' as needed. In the previous example it first creates "C:\Test\Test1" and
' only then creates "C:\Test\Test1\Test2" in it.
' The function returns 'True' if the folder previously existed or now exists.
' The function returns 'False' if 'PathString' is invalid.
Function createFolders(PathString As String) As Boolean
    
    ' Initialize error handling.
    Const ProcName As String = "createFolders"
    On Error GoTo clearError ' Turn on error trapping.

    ' Split Path String ('PathString') by System Path Separator ('Delimiter')
    ' into 1D zero-based Folders Array 'Folders()'.
    Dim Delimiter As String
    Delimiter = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim Folders() As String
    Folders = Split(PathString, Delimiter)
    
    ' Define Last Subscript ('LastSS') to be considered, because Path String
    ' could be ending with a System Path Separator.
    Dim LastSS As Long
    LastSS = UBound(Folders)
    If Folders(LastSS) = "" Then
        LastSS = LastSS - 1
    End If
    
    ' Using Folders Array, write paths to Paths Array ('Paths()').
    Dim Paths() As String
    ReDim Paths(0 To LastSS)
    Paths(0) = Folders(0)
    Dim j As Long
    If LastSS > 0 Then
        For j = 1 To LastSS
            Paths(j) = Paths(j - 1) & Delimiter & Folders(j)
        Next j
    End If
    
    ' Create each folder if it does not exist.
    For j = 0 To LastSS
        If Dir(Paths(j), vbDirectory) = "" Then
            MkDir Paths(j)
        End If
    Next j
    
    ' Write result.
    createFolders = True
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Function

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error trapping.
    GoTo ProcExit
    
End Function

Sub testCreateFolders()
    Const PathString As String = "C:\Test\Test1\Test2"
    Dim Result As Boolean
    Result = createFolders(PathString)
    If Result Then
        MsgBox "If the path previously didn't exist, now it certainly does."
    Else
        MsgBox "The supplied path is invalid."
    End If
End Sub

Sub testMkDir()
    Const PathString As String = "C:\Test\Test1\Test2"
    MkDir PathString
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi VBasic, Firstly what a totally awesome effort.  Really blown away by your detailed solution.  I've ran the tests as instructed in a fresh Excel file. and started with one column at a time.  The file/folder messages write in the specified columns but doesn't work correctly or as expected.  Ran the complete set of test starting with just adding data in column A and re-running with column B, C and finally D.  Not sure how to upload the excel file to show you what I'm testing??

Comment: I forgot to mention that the paths should not have a trailing backslash \ and I now see that I mixed up the columns (I thought `folder, folder, file, file`): instead of `"A", "B", "C", "D"` use `"A", "C", "B", "D"`

Comment: Great, that improved the results.  Cant post a file or screen dump (too new to this forum), so here goes.  A=C:\temp3\Source, B=C:\temp3\Destination, C=1.txt, D=10.txt    Results PASS with E Copy = Success & F Source Exists = TRUE.  Run the test again and all is good - Copy = Fail, SourceFile = Duplicate

Comment: It fails on the next lines where:   A=C:\temp3\Source\Original1, B=C:\temp3\Destination\01, C=3.txt, D=12.txt  - Copy=Fail & Source=FALSE

Comment: It should mean that folder `C:\temp3\Source\Original1` doesn't exist, because `Source= FALSE`. It would be `Source=duplicate` if folder exists and `12.txt` exists.

Comment: I've added a screen dump "TestFile2" at the top of my post to hopefully better show what I'm doing as C:\temp3\Source\Original1 does exist.

Comment: I was wrong again, it should mean that one of the folders does not exist. Although it is unknown which one. If both folders exist, column `F` will contain either `TRUE` or `"duplicate"`. So I would conclude that `C:\temp3\Destination\01` does not exist.

Comment: ahhh, yes the Destination folder doesnt contain sub folders.  Tkx, I'II give it another go tomorrow.  I'm just hanging in here as its 1am in the morning :) and need to get some sleep. Tkx

Comment: ...couldn't help myself. :)  one last test before I get some sleep.  See screen dump at to of post "TestFile3"  Row 8 didn't get the expected outcome.

Comment: @Bart101: I've edited the code for `copyRenameFile` only. This should be it.

Comment: Solid Solution, works flawlessly.  Tested with Mapped share drives and long UNC paths with no issues.  Thankyou very much :)  Added screen dump "Solution Template SetUp" at top for anyone else looking to apply the solution

Comment: The "Create Folders" byproduct solution:  How do I apply?  I've tested in a new module and at the tail end of the main solution.  My thinking was it will either create the missing destination folder/s listed in column B of the prev solution or will create a folder structure based on a "List" in column A eg: C:\temp3\Destination\03NewFolder

Comment: @Bart101: You just use `createFolders "C:\temp3\Destination\03NewFolder"` and if `03NewFolder` doesn't exist, it will be created. If `Destination` doesn't exist, it will be created before `03NewFolder` is created and so on. You can also check the 'validity' of the path with e.g. `bolCheck = createFolders("Z:\temp")`, when on one hand the folder `temp` will be created if it doesn't exist and in both cases `bolCheck` will return `True`, or on the other hand, if drive `Z` does not exist, `bolCheck` will return `False`.

Comment: I can also see a use for this to move files but with an initial dialog box "Warning, you are about to move and rename files, Press OK to continue, Press Cancel to stop".  Any chance of posting a modified version for this purpose or should I create a new thread?